# Existence and characterisations of left Kan extensions and liftings in the bicategory of relations I

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories, kan-extension

The bicategory $\mathsf{Rel}$ of sets, relations, and inclusions of relations has right Kan extensions and right Kan lifts¹, however I believe it does not have all left Kan extensions/lifts.

1. Is it indeed the case that $\mathsf{Rel}$ does not have all left Kan extensions/lifts?
2. (Moved to a [sequel question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461592))
3. Is there an if and only if characterisation of the stronger condition of having
   $$\mathrm{Lan}_S\colon\mathsf{Rel}(A,X)\to\mathsf{Rel}(B,X)$$
   exist for a relation $S\colon A⇸B$ in terms of properties of $S$?

---

¹I'll add a reference here with full proofs for this in the future.

Comment: Question 1 is "easy" to evade: a 1-cell in a bicategory has a left adjoint if and only if $Lan_F1$ exists (and it turns out to be an absolute extension). So, take a relation that doesn't have a right adjoint. I am not aware of a sharp theorem for 2 or 3, but certainly some Lan's exist and some don't. I'd start assuming something on $S$ (it is total, univalued, functional...) and see what happens. (I am ashamed I never thought about this before!)

Comment: Note that the hom-categories of $Rel$ are co/complete lattices, and the composition functor preserves colimits in each variable. So by the adjoint functor theorem, right Kan extensions / lifts exist as you indicate, and left Kan extensions / lifts exist in the sense of your (3) if and only if the relevant composition functors preserve limits (which doesn't happen in general).

Comment: @fosco oooh I forgot about the $Lan_F1$ characterisation, that's super useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial answer, addressing (3). Given a relation $S : A⇸B$, composition with $S$ is a cocontinuous order-preserving map $Rel(B,C) \to Rel(A,C)$. These hom-posets are powerset lattices $2^{B\times C}$ and $2^{A \times C}$, which are complete. By the adjoint functor theorem, this map has a right adjoint giving the right Kan extension as you indicated in the question.

In order for a left adjoint to exist, by the adjoint functor theorem it is necessary and sufficient for composition with $S$ to preserve limits. If $C = \emptyset$, this is always the case. Otherwise, $C$ admits $1$ as a retract, and we reduce to this case. So for left Kan extensions to exist when $C \neq \emptyset$, it is necessary and sufficient for $S$ to admit a left adjoint in $Rel$, i.e. for $S$ to be the graph of a function $f : A \to B$. Dually, for all left Kan lifts to exist when $C \neq \emptyset$, it is necessary and sufficient for $S$ to be the dual graph of a function $f : B \to A$.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you so much for the answer! Do you happen to know an explicit description for left Kan extensions (resp. lifts) along $S=\mathrm{Gr}(f)$ (resp. along the relation $b\mapsto f^{-1}(b)$)?