# Existence and characterisations of left Kan extensions and liftings in the bicategory of relations II

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories, kan-extension

This is the second part to a previous question regarding left Kan extensions/lifts in the bicategory $\mathsf{Rel}$ of sets, relations, and inclusions of relations, which has now been split into two questions.

1. Given relations $S\colon A⇸X$ and $R\colon A⇸B$, is there a characterisation of when the left Kan extension/lift
   \begin{align*}
   \mathrm{Lan}_S(R) &\colon B⇸X,\\
   \mathrm{Lift}_S(R)&\colon X⇸A
   \end{align*}
   exist, in terms of properties of $S$ and $R$?
2. As Tim Campion [pointed out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/460693) in Part I of this question, the left Kan extension and left Kan lift
   \begin{align*}
   \mathrm{Lan}_S &\colon\mathsf{Rel}(A,X)⇸\mathsf{Rel}(B,X),\\
   \mathrm{Lift}_S&\colon\mathsf{Rel}(X,B)⇸\mathsf{Rel}(X,A)
   \end{align*}
   along a relation $S\colon A⇸B$ exist iff $S$ is respectively the graph $\mathrm{Gr}(f)$ of a function $f$ or the inverse graph $b\mapsto f^{-1}(b)$ of $f$. In these two cases, are there explicit descriptions for $\mathrm{Lan}_S$ and $\mathrm{Lift}_S$?